# How content type field can get a value from a view

Tags: entities, organic-groups

I need a field in my OG content type to get a numerical value from an existing view (OG members base table), so that I can use Computed Field module to run a simple calculation against the value of another field on the same node ($z=$x/$y).

FWIW the view result is the count of members within the group to which the content type belongs. The view has a 'content:nid' contextual filter with a 'group node from OG membership' relationship, if that's worth mentioning.

I've used the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module to display the value on each node, however Computed Field cannot see it. I considered doing the desired calculation within another view, but I believe it would be more efficient in my case to run the calculation upon saving each node.

I'm using Drupal 7.37 with OG 7.x-2.7 and Views 7.x-3.1.

If you have a suggestion that involves some coding, I would be very grateful for any guidance as I'm a total php noob.